Add order item price per kilo in WooCommerce New Order notification
I want to add the price per kilogram of an item to the admin-new-order.php template. I've managed to get the weight and quantity and to echo it (see "104" in screenshot) in the admin-new-order.php and customer-completed-order.php templates by adding the following code to email-order-items.php template file:
$product = $item->get_product();
$product_weight = $product->get_weight();
echo $product_weight;
$qty = $item->get_quantity();
echo $qty;

What I'm missing is the price variable (see "82,80" screenshot) so I can echo a calculation like this:
echo ($subtotal / $product_weight / $qty);

I haven't figured out how to get the item subtotal to echo a calculation with variables yet. But primarily I need to get the the item subtotal, which is shown in the screenshot below.

Afterward I want to echo my calculation as mentioned above. Ideally, this should show in the admin-new-order.php template only. But if it's only possible to show it in both emails by putting the code in the email-order-items.php it's fine as well.

Your question is a bit unclear… Where precisely (exact location), and how (the desired formatting), do you want to display the price per weight unit?

I want to place it in the admin-new-order.php email as text right after the sku (in the same table cell where it shows the title/image, product name and sku) like this: "2,33 €/kg". Exactly where you see "104" in the screenshot.

An advice: Always try to use available hooks, instead of overriding templates.
The following will display the product price by Kilo under the SKU on email order items only for New Order notification:
// Setting the email ID as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'set_the_email_id_as_a_global_variable', 1, 4);
function set_the_email_id_as_a_global_variable($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $GLOBALS['email_id'] = $email->id;
}

// Display product price by Kilo under the product SKU
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'display_remaining_stock_quantity', 10, 3 );
function display_remaining_stock_quantity( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    // Only for order item "line item" type
    if ( !$item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        return;
    }
    $globalsVar = $GLOBALS; // Pass $GLOBALS variable as reference

    // Target New Order Email notification 
    if( isset($globalsVar['email_id']) && $globalsVar['email_id'] === 'new_order' ) {
        $product  = $item->get_product();
        $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
        $weight   = $product->get_weight();

        if ( $weight > 0 ) {        
            if ( 'excl' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' ) ) {
                $subtotal = $order->get_line_subtotal( $item );
            } else {
                $subtotal = $order->get_line_subtotal( $item, true );
            }
            $price_per_kg = $subtotal / $quantity / $weight;
            $price_args   = array('currency' => $order->get_currency());

            echo '<div>' . wc_price( $price_per_kg, $price_args ) . '/kg</div>';
        }
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
Make sure that the template email-order-items.php is the default WooCommerce one, without any modifications.

Perfect, many thanks! I was looking for hooks, but couldn't find any that suited my needs. I was able to modify your code and added the $weight in the echo: echo '<div>' . $weight . ' kg/Pkg, ' . wc_price( $price_per_kg, $price_args ) . '/kg</div>';

As I understand it, you want to modify the admin-new-order.php email.
A way to do it is to hook into the action 'woocommerce_email_order_details' and output all the information you need there.
Example:
if ( ! function_exists( 'phr4pp_modify_woocommerce_email_order_details' ) ) {
    function phr4pp_modify_woocommerce_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
        echo 'text here!';
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'phr4pp_modify_woocommerce_email_order_details', 10, 4 );
}

Changing the priority (third parameter in add_action()) to a lower number will display the text before anything else.
The above code could go into the file functions.php inside your theme.

How does this solve the issue? You are talking about hooking into woocommerce_email_order_details but "your" sample code is hooking phr4pp_modify_woocommerce_email_order_details. What's up with this? Unsure what the echo "text here"; is supposed to do either

So the action is named woocommerce_email_order_details and the function which will run is named phr4pp_modify_woocommerce_email_order_details().
Hooking to the action woocommerce_email_order_details allows you to add the price per kilo information.
The echo "text here" is supposed to represent were the code about adding the per kilo info will go.
